# R - How to create a new character vector which does not contain a specific value

Tags: r

I've got a character vector, for example ("A" "B" "C" "0"). How can I create out of this a new vector which does not contain any "0" zero characters?

Therefore, the output should be ("A" "B" "C").

Thank you very much! :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
x = c("A", "B", "C", "0", "D")
y = x[x != "0"]
```

`x != "0"` gives you a logical vector which you can use for indexing the original one.